# Coding a MAP feature in MS Access 2016

Tags: bing-maps

I have a database project (in MS Access 2016) and wish to add a mapping feature with the following functionality (via VBA is preferred);

1 – Create a FORM that includes display of a street map of a specific small city overall view (I can get the desired starting URL from Google or Bing maps). This can fill on Open or via a command button.

2 – The user manipulates that map’s controls in order to locate a target point that they desire, and manually MARK (such as by pushpin) that point.

3 – After marking the point they can press a command button which will then acquire the latitude and longitude of the point so marked (pushpin) and store that data in the current recordset. If that marked map image can be stored as a .jpg or similar, that would be a “bonus”.

4 – On the REPORT associated with that recordset, I would like to include a subREPORT that is an image of that map showing that pushpin…… either using the SAVED .jpg image OR created dynamically at Preview/Print so that it appears in the printed REPORT (whichever method is easier to code).

Comment: So, what is your question? What have you tried?